# Blank page showing in django server after adding python in index.html file

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Please help I'm following a tutorial and not showing desierd output in the server page.
Every thing was going smoothly until the `index.html` page content not shown.

This is my `index.html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="eng">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <title>document</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                **{% for Product in product_objetcs %}**
                <div class="col-md-3">
                   <div class="card">
                   <img src="{{ product.image }}" class="card-img-top">
                   <div class="card-body">
                       <div class="card-title">
                               **{{ product.tittle }}**
                           </div>
                       <div class="card-text">
                              **{{ product.price }}**
                       </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              **{% endfor %}**
                </div>
             </div>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This my views page

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from.models import Product

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    product_objects = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request,
```

My models page looks like this

```
from django.db import models

    # Create your models here.
    class Product(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        price = models.FloatField()
        discount_price = models.FloatField()
        category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        description = models.TextField()
         image = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

Comment: Welcome To the Community Mohamed,  show your views not just a part you need to show the whole `return render`

Comment: and this (`image = models.CharField(max_length=300)`) is not correct for an image. you should use something like this `image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')`

Comment: you use `for Product ...` with upper `P` but later you use `product.image` with lower `p` and this is different variable.

Comment: Moreover the aforementioned hints, why `render(request,` is interrupted? Also,  indention before `image = models.CharField(max_length=300) ` is not observed.